# Use an object instead of multiple parameters and files in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an `@RestController` that allows to POST with a few `@RequestParam` arguments and 2 `@RequestPart` arguments to be able to create an object in the service layer that needs some input + 2 files like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity createBook(@RequestParam("authorId") UUID authorId,
                                           @RequestParam("pages") int pages,                                               
                                           @RequestParam("rating") BookRating rating,
                                           @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
                                           @RequestPart("file2") MultipartFile file2) {
```

I would like to create an object that encapsulates all those parameters, so I can do something like:

```
public ResponseEntity createBook( CreateBookParameters params ) {
```

How do I do this? What annotation do I need to use in my controller? Are there any annotations I need to use in the `CreateBookParameters` or is this a simple POJO ?

Do I need to change anything to the request I do if I do these changes (I am testing with "form-data" setting in Postman)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can roll the multipart into it, but you can collect all the `@RequestParam`s into an `@ModelAttribute CreateBookParameters`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Spring's default reflection behavior? Try this:

```
public class CreateBookParameters {
    private UUID authorId;
    private int pages;
    private BookRating rating;
    private MultipartFile file;
    private MultipartFile file2;

    // add getters & setters for each
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity createBook(CreateBookParameters p) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That works! I tried about any possible annotation, but I never tried without any annotation at all. Seems I *can* annotate with `@Valid` in the controller method and use `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` in the `CreateBookParameters` object and Spring will validate it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to take a look at the [@RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotation and see if you can use that.